# Example for offset_surface function on python

Tags: python, mesh

I would appreciate it if I can see an example for using [offset_surface](https://libigl.github.io/libigl-python-bindings/igl_docs/#offset_surface) on python as follow:

- read object in stl format
- offset object with certain distance
- write new object (offsetted object) in stl as well.

long story short, I am looking for something like [this](https://www.alecjacobson.com/weblog/?tag=offset) but with **python** instead of **matlab**

Thank you so much

I tried it here:

```
from igl import read_triangle_mesh, offset_surface
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os.path
isolevel = 2
s = 100
signed_distance_type = 0
[v, f] = read_triangle_mesh("STL_files.stl")
print(v, f)

[SV, SF] = offset_surface(v, f, isolevel, s, signed_distance_type)
print(SV, SF)
```

But ended up with this error:

```
[SV, SF] = offset_surface(v, f, isolevel, s, signed_distance_type)
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the answer for the question and wanted to shar it wit you:

instead of

```
[SV, SF] = offset_surface(v, f, isolevel, s, signed_distance_type)
print(SV, SF)
```

we can do :

```
Out = offset_surface(V, F, isolevel, s, signed_distance_type)
print(Out[0]) # To print Vertices
print(Out[1]) # To print Faces
```